# Given a finite abelian group $G$ with $g \in G$, then for any divisor $d$ of $|g|$ there is an element of $G$ with order $d$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

From an homework question that comes as an introduction to abelian groups. Regarding my efforts to solve the question, I have been trying to utilize the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, or that:

$G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{k_1} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{k_2} \ldots \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{k_n}$

Wherein $k_1 \ldots k_n$ are powers of primes and $k_i | k_{i+1}$ for $0 < i \leq n$. It was the latter of those two properties that I felt was pertinent to the question. However, after playing around prime powers and factorizations, I did not conclude anything relevant to the original question. I sense I am not approaching this as I should be, because this property seems genuinely simple.

Is there some other manipulation of properties of abelian groups from which this falls out straightforwardly, or alternatively am I not properly understanding the fundamental theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working too hard. Suppose that $|g| = 6$. Then, for example, 2 divides 6. Look at the elements $e, g, g^2, g^3, g^4, g^5$. Can you see one of them that has order 2? Which one? Now try to generalize, and you'll be done. (This works even for non-abelian groups!).

Comment: Forgive me if I am misunderstanding your answer (again, I know little of group theory), but doesn't that sort of grouping and reasoning relate to cyclic groups only?

Comment: Edit: Oh wait, I get what you're saying. This really is something quite general. Looks like I got caught in the details.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Use Cauchy's theorem for groups.

I am surprised that you are trying to use the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups for this question. This theorem is usually presented in a second course in group theory.